# Does 2sxc module have ability to contain external module object similarly to inserting App/Content into wysiwyg editor?

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I know that DNN doesn't support inserting of one module inside another one. But I wonder if 2sxc module has workaround for it and just like you can, lets say, insert gallery application in blog post content, is there a way to insert there external module object?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no. 2sxc doesn't have this functionality built in.

BUT: DNN does have some APIs to do this - there were modules that did this kind of stuff. So I would continue in the DNN APIs to figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the answer is yes, and that you should take a look at https://docs.2sxc.org/api/dot-net/ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.Factory.html.  I think that you should be looking at CmsBlock.

Some other references:

- https://docs.2sxc.org/specs/architecture/data-flow.html
  https://docs.2sxc.org/api/dot-net/ToSic.Sxc.DataSources.CmsBlock.html

I've never done anything like this, and I'm not really familiar with the content on this page.  Perhaps Daniel and give us both some pointers.

Comment: Seems like it's designed only to work with another 2sxc module. I created `IBlockBuilder` object with `Factory.CmsBlock` method, and then displayed it using `@Html.Raw(blockBuilder.Render())` but its behaviour seems strange to me. When I give it ModuleId and TabId for my custom DNN module object (not 2sxc application!) - it displayes empty 2sxc module container with non-working menu. And with existing 2sxc module's ModuleId and TabId it renders same page recursively until `Error: System.InsufficientExecutionStackException` occars. Is it designed to work with another 2sxc module instance only?